# qooxdoo: implementing virtual scrolling list

Tags: qooxdoo

I try to implement a virtual scrolling loading qx.ui.mobile.list.List. At least a lazy loading one. There is no event available by qooxdoo to know when the List is scrolled to the end. Is there some way to know the 'onScrollEnd' event or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team added the feature in August, called *waypoints*. Here's [the post](http://news.qooxdoo.org/waypoints-feature-added-to-qx-mobile). You need to define offsets at which you wish the event to be risen. Here's example from the post to illustrate the idea.

```
var scrollContainer = page._getScrollContainer();
scrollContainer.setWaypointsY(["0%", "50%", "100%", 200, ".waypoint"]);

scrollContainer.addListener("waypoint", function(evt) 
{
  console.log("Waypoint reached:" + evt.getData());
}, this);
```

Event payload has the following structure.

```
{
  "offset"  : 0,
  "input"   : "10%",
  "index"   : 0,
  "element" : 0
}
```

There's also a complete demo in mobile showcase of lazy-loading list implemented with waypoints: [showcase](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/mobileshowcase/index.html#%2Flist), [code](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/application/mobileshowcase/source/class/mobileshowcase/page/List.js).